# Torque Paradox, regarding friction and two rotating objects

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, torque, free-body-diagram

Say I have a rotating disk #1, that is connected via an axle to disk #2 with a person on it. Disk #1 has a torque about the axle from the person via the applied force at the edge and it rotates CCW. The person & Disk #2 would revolve around the axis with a CW direction.

But how does the person move or get any torque to do so? The reaction of the applied force on the person would be cancelled by the friction force from Disk #2. Since they are at equal radi, the torques would cancel.  The friction force on disk #2 would be cancelled from the axle force. However, there would be a net torque on disk #2.  The total force x-direction of the system(disk #1, Disk #2 and person) would cancel as it is internal. The only torque would be to disk #2, yet the person revolves with the disk?

What am I confusing or missing?

[image]

Comment: To clarify, Disk 1 and disk 2 are concentric to the same axle, but they are not influencing each other via the axle. They rotate independently of each other if the person is not touching both. Is that the situation?

Comment: Yes they are concentric. Only the person touches disk #1, and therefore person/disk #2 rotate away to conserve angular momemtum. However, what i dont get is it appears the person has no torque, yet they spin with disk #2? How does that work

Comment: why do you assume that the friction on the person from disk 1 is the same as that applied to disk 2?

Comment: The person is standing on disk #2. The only friction force on the person is from disk 2, not disk 1. Since it is static friction, they should be equal. Also, if you look at the entire system, the forces in the x direction have to cancel out as there is no transnational motion, just rotation.

Comment: Your question lacks a lot of information. Does the person move relative to disk 1? Does the person move relative to disk 2? In what reference frame are you calculating torques? In what reference frame are you calculating accelerations? You must consider all these questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The reaction of the applied force on the person would be cancelled by the friction force from Disk #2

That doesn't happen.  We can consider the friction between the person and disk2 to be sufficient so that they don't slide.  Therefore the person and disk2 can be considered a single solid object.

When the person pushes on disk1, there is a force couple created.  Disk 1 has a force in one direction (which create a torque), and the disk2/person object has a force in the other direction (which creates a torque in the other direction).

Friction here couples the person to disk2, it does not cancel or eliminate the torque.

> But when i break them down, wouldn't friction and the reaction force from disk #1 cancel out on the person?

No, the friction force must be smaller, so they don't cancel.  Let's look closely at the friction force.  It forms another couple, one part of the force is "forward" on the person (same direction the person is pushing disk 1), and the other part is "backward" on disk 2.

This second part of the friction force has nothing to oppose it.  We can show it to be $F=ma$, where the friction force accelerates disk2.  Since the person is attached to the disk, the person accelerates as well.

If you want to look at the person and the disks as 3 elements, then there is no cancelling the force on disk1, and there is no cancelling the friction on disk2.  Both will cause accelerations and motions.

> I am not understanding. If i sit on a chair, i cannot push myself. In this example, the person is essentially pushing on disk 1, which pushes into the axle, which cancels out the reaction force.

No.  If the person pushes disk1 toward the axle, that would happen.  But then there would be zero motion and the problem is boring.  But we assume the person is trying to turn the wheel.  In that case there is a component of the force that is tangential, and the axle doesn't cancel.  disk1 goes one way and the person/disk2 goes the other way.

And yes, because the person's mass is not aligned with the axis, as the person moves, the axle will move to keep the center of mass in the same position (assuming the axle isn't fixed to some object).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115072/discussion-on-answer-by-bowlofred-torque-paradox-regarding-friction-and-two-rot).

Answer (score 0):

You are right that the torques applied to disk $1$ and disk $2$ are equal and opposite. But disk $1$ is smaller than disk $2$ so it presumably has a smaller moment of inertia than disk $2$. So disk $1$ will rotate more quickly counter clockwise than disk $2$ rotates clockwise.

Comment: I agree with that, but why does the person rotate with disk #2? The person appears to have no torque on them. But yet they spin around the axle as part of disk #2. Is it because the person doesn't spin relative to the axle independently of the disk#2,  so we have to treat the person and disk #2 as one object?

Comment: @KevinCSpeltz If the person stands still on disk $2$ and gives disk $1$ a push and lets go then they will rotate with disk $2$. But if they hold on to disk $1$ and walk forward on disk $2$ then they can rotate with disk $1$ instead.

Comment: That is not answering my question though. If you look at the person, where is the torque on them about the axis of rotation? If you look at the forces on the person, dont these cancel out as well as the torques? yet they rotate with disk #2, that is where i am confused

Comment: @KevinCSpeltz While the person pushes on disk $1$  and the net force on them is zero then their centre of mass is stationary -they do not rotate with disk $2$. Once they let go of disk $1$ then the friction force on them is unbalanced and their centre of mass accelerates until they are at rest with respect to disk $2$ - unless disk $2$ is rotating too fast for friction to provide enough centripetal force, in which case they slide off.

Comment: the person pushes off disk 1. They are never holding on. As soon as they push off disk 1, disk 1 would rotate. So would the person and disk #2. I am trying to understand how the person rotates. Bowl of Red comments below might help explain the problem i have.

Answer (score 0):

If the person remains stationary with respect to the bottom disk (#2), then there is a static friction force because the person accelerates. You do not know the direction of the friction force, but it has both radial and tangential components. The radial component of the friction will have a magnitude of $$|a_r|=m\omega^2 r$$ and the tangential component will be $$|a_t|=m\alpha r,$$
where $\alpha$ is the angular acceleration of the person/#2 disk system.

Disk #1 exerts a static friction, tangentially, on the person's hands, but the person's torso accelerates due to muscular forces. If the motion of the person is acceleration around the axle  then there must be a net torque on the person about that axle. That net torque comes from *both* the tangential static frictions, which are separate forces and not equal as evidenced by the fact that the person accelerates relative to disk#1. The torques are opposite each other, but they are not equal! The static friction of the person on disk #2 produces the torque about the axle on #2, and the angular accelerations are, by definition of your problem, the same. If they were not the same, the person would move relative to both disks.

Comment: I assume the person does not move on disk #2, but rotates with it, as they are held by static friction. The person would rotate with respect to the axis and yes move with respect to disk 1.

Comment: I was also assuming I was measuring this from a fixed frame, but it was like both disks where in space so one could revolve opposite of the other.

Comment: My mistake I think was thinking the reaction force from disk1 was going to cancel out the friction force from disk2  on the person. However  the person is still moving as they rotate with disk 2. So they cannot be  equal, there is a difference. This allows the person and disk #2 to rotate, but stay together. Do you agree or am I missing more? Sorry there are days I wish I was back in college to ask these questions